# after using javascript to show a div after 700px how do i hide it?

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout, scrolltop

I have a div in a wordpress site, which is set via css to display: none; on page load.

I then use:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()>700){
     $("#logo-scroll").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

to fade it in after 700px. I cannot work out how to hide it again after 2200px.

I have tried:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()>700){
     $("#logo-scroll").fadeIn();
  }
  else if($(window).scrollTop()>2200){
     $("#logo-scroll").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

but it shows it at the right time but doesnt effect the fade out at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the first `if` statement is always evaluating to true after the window has been scrolled beyond 700px ... The second `else if` statement is never executed. So you need to make it so it only evaluates to true between the 700px and 2200px scroll-positions.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();

  if(scroll_position > 700 && scroll_position <= 2200){
    $("#logo-scroll").fadeIn();
  }
  else if(scroll_position > 2200){
    $("#logo-scroll").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `&& $(window).scrollTop() < 2200` to get:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 700 && $(window).scrollTop() < 2200){
     $("#logo-scroll").fadeIn();
  }
  else if($(window).scrollTop()>2200){
     $("#logo-scroll").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Your first `if` statement evaluates as true, even if you want to hide it, you immediatly show it again.